# Is it possible to add an error to a CollectionType field specifically?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to add an error to a CollectionType "field" in a Symfony form.

In my Symfony form, I have, amongst other fields, a CollectionType:

```
            ->add('collCases', CollectionType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => "Cases :",
                'entry_type' => TextType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                ],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ])
```

In my controller, I then have a condition, under which I add an error to a couple of fields.
For a TextType field, it works just fine (it is displayed with `{{ form_errors(form.name) }}` in the Twig template):

```
$form->get('name')->addError(new FormError("Your name is not formatted correctly."));
```

However, when I try to do the same for my CollectionType field, the error gets added to the form itself instead of the collection (it is displayed with `{{ form_errors(form) }}` rather than `{{ form_errors(form.collCases) }}`:

```
$form->get('collCases')->addError(new FormError("At least one case number is not formatted correctly."));
```

Is it possible to add the error to the CollectionType?

Comment: You are adding the error to the CollectionType, which is part of the parent form. You want to add the error to the embedded TextType inside the collection. Try `foreach($form->get('collCases') as $text){$text->addError(...)}`

Comment: @ArleighHix I do want to add it to the CollectionType though, but it gets added to the CollectionType's parent.